# c++ function return type error

Tags: c++, function

while writing a function to extract the minimum of a linked list , i'm having problems with the return type, i am using a templates and i am trying to change from the type of the template to the desired type. what should i do. thank you :)

here is the code:

```
Type linkedListType<Type>::extractMin()const{
assert (last!=NULL);
nodeType<Type> *current;
nodeType<Type> *minval;
current = first;
 minval=first;
while (current != NULL) //search the list
{
    if (current->info < minval->info) //searchItem is found
    {
        minval=current;
        current=current->link;
    }
    else
        current = current->link; //make current point to next node

}
return minval;}
```

Comment: Well `minval` is a `nodeType<Type>*`, and your function returns just `Type`. We don't see the definition of `NodeType`, so you will have to extract the value from that somehow. Maybe like `return minval->getValue();`

Comment: `minval` is  of type `nodeType<Type>*` but the function return type is `Type`.

Comment: Why is your indentation so strange?

Answer (score 0):

Your function has the signature

```
Type linkedListType<Type>::extractMin() const
```

But you try to return

```
return minval;
```

Which has the type

```
nodeType<Type>* minval;
```

So you are returning a `nodeType<Type>*` when you said you would return a `Type`.

Answer (score 0):

> Type linkedListType::extractMin() const

You're returning `Type`.

> nodeType *minval

However, you're trying to do `return minval` but `minval` is of type `nodeType<Type>*` (i.e., you're not returning `Type`).

Instead you probably need to return one of the members for `minval`. For example something like

```
return minval->value;
```

but since we don't know what the code looks like for `nodeType` we can't say exactly how to resolve the issue.

Comment: so what should i do? i am new to programming so please help. thank you

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to answer (i.e., we don't know anything about `nodeType<Type>`) but somewhere there is a `Type` that stores the _value_ and that is what would be returned (e.g., `return minval->value;`).